# Creating barchart ggplot2 single dim dataframe

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a barchart in ggplot2, I have a dataframe that has column names and associated numeric values, but I keep running into unexpected errors creating the dataframe:

```
ggplot(audit_count,aes(x=colnames(audit_count),y=audit_count[1,])) +geom_bar()
```

gives me error message

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x, y
```

But this error message doesnt make sense to me, as colnames(audit_count) and audit_count[1,] are the same length.

Is there some kind of transform I need to do to my data to get it to plot as barchart with the column names as bar names, and the numeric values as y values?

Data below:

```
structure(list(page_title_missing = 56L, page_title_length = 164L, 
    page_title_duplicates = 630L, meta_desc_missing = 703L, meta_desc_length = 0L, 
    meta_desc_duplicate = 28L, url_dynamic = 397L, url_underscore = 26L, 
    url_uppercase = 701L, pagination = 0L, image_alt_missing = 223L, 
    h1_missing = 56L, h1_multiple = 427L, meta_keyword_present = 0L, 
    https_missing = 0L, non_canonical = 293L, meta_no_index = 0L, 
    meta_no_follow = 0L, content_duplication = 617L, content_depth = 461L, 
    non_301_redirects = 55L, redirec_chains = 56L, errors_404 = 0L, 
    mobile_url_inconsisten = 0L, hreflang_missing = 731L), .Names = c("page_title_missing", 
"page_title_length", "page_title_duplicates", "meta_desc_missing", 
"meta_desc_length", "meta_desc_duplicate", "url_dynamic", "url_underscore", 
"url_uppercase", "pagination", "image_alt_missing", "h1_missing", 
"h1_multiple", "meta_keyword_present", "https_missing", "non_canonical", 
"meta_no_index", "meta_no_follow", "content_duplication", "content_depth", 
"non_301_redirects", "redirec_chains", "errors_404", "mobile_url_inconsisten", 
"hreflang_missing"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ggplot expects data to be in a tidy format and `aes()` should map columns of a data.frame to a graphic property. You aren't really meant to pass the data directly to an aes. One quick fix is

```
ggplot(tidyr::gather(audit_count, variable, value)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(x=variable,y=value), stat="identity") +
    coord_flip()
```

or

```
ggplot(reshape2::melt(audit_count)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(x=variable,y=value), stat="identity") +
    coord_flip()
```

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware ggplot2 expected data in that way.

Answer (score 0):

I would transpose the data with `t()` and then feed in the `rownames()` as the x and `V1` as the y into the ggplot. in the `geom_bar()`, `stat = 'identity'` signifies to use the values as the bar length

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

audit_count <- t(audit_count) %>% as.data.frame
ggplot(audit_count, aes(x = rownames(audit_count), y = V1)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + coord_flip()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, does the data have to be in a long format for ggplot to accept it?

Comment: Yea, pretty much.